# Make palindrome from given word

Tags: algorithm

I have given word like `abca`. I want to know how many letters do I need to add to make it palindrome.
In this case its 1, because if I add b, I get `abcba`.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem ;-) Write out a few examples on paper and *think* about it. Hint: Take words that you know how many more letters need to be added, and try to inductively extrapolate how you can calculate it in the general case. So look at a word that needs 1, then look at a word that needs 2, then look at a word that needs 3, etc. until you see a pattern. Surely the human mind is capable of *some* pattern matching; why I could swear that there are at least millions of neurons in your head. Use them!

Comment: look on a tag :) and thanks for help :)

Comment: Do you want to find out the FEWEST number of letters to add? Because you can always just append the reverse of the string and have a palindrome.

Comment: @Dan W I want fewest. thats th problem :/

Comment: can you re-arrange the letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's consider an inefficient recursive solution:

Suppose the string is of the form `aSb`, where `a` and `b` are letters and `S` is a substring.

If `a==b`, then `f(aSb) = f(S)`.

If `a!=b`, then you need to add a letter: either add an `a` at the end, or add a `b` in the front. We need to try both and see which is better. So in this case, `f(aSb) = 1 + min(f(aS), f(Sb))`.

This can be implemented with a recursive function which will take exponential time to run.

To improve performance, note that this function will only be called with substrings of the original string. There are only O(n^2) such substrings. So by [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results of this function, we reduce the time taken to O(n^2), at the cost of O(n^2) space.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm would look like this:

- Iterate over the half the string and check if a character exists at the appropriate position at the other end (i.e., if you have `abca` then the first character is an `a` and the string also ends with `a`).

  - If they match, then proceed to the next character.
  - If they don't match, then note that a character needs to be added.

Note that you can only move backwords from the end when the characters match. For example, if the string is `abcdeffeda` then the outer characters match. We then need to consider `bcdeffed`. The outer characters don't match so a `b` needs to be added. But we don't want to continue with `cdeffe` (i.e., removing/ignoring both outer characters), we simply remove `b` and continue with looking at `cdeffed`. Similarly for `c` and this means our algorithm returns `2` string modifications and not more.

Comment: This has the same issue as user1168577's answer: when you have the string `bcdeffed`, you don't know whether to add `b` at the end or `d` at the start. If you just decide to add `b` you won't necessarily get the best answer.

Comment: @interjay: Hmm, we could introduce backtracking to search for the minimal number of modifications. So whenever a character needs to be added, add either `b` or `d` and continue your search. When you're done, look at all possible answers that you've found and return the one with the least number of modifications.

Comment: backtracking will make the solution exponential in time, which is suboptimal unless the problem is NP-Hard.. [to be honest, I am clueless if it is NP-Hard or not... I have no intuition regarding this one]